# convert unix timestamp string to readable date using pandas libraries

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

```
unix_timestamp=1284105682
print(pd.to_datetime(unix_timestamp,unit='s',origin='unix'))
```

Expected Output : 2010-09-10 13:31:22
My Output: 2010-09-10 08:01:22

I am unable to figure out how time is getting wrong

Comment: Isn't it an UTC issue?

Comment: Seems like your in another time zone than UTC.

Comment: Converting the timezone to `Asia/Calcutta` gives the expected output.

Comment: how to convert timezone to Asia/Kolkata

Comment: For Asia/Kolkata just change the `tz_convert` to `tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a UTC-related issue. You can create the datetime with UTC and then change it to your time-zone like this:

```
import pandas as pd
unix_timestamp=1284105682
df = pd.to_datetime(unix_timestamp, unit='s', origin='unix', utc=True)
df.tz_convert('America/Sao_Paulo')
```

Comment: using tz_convert showing this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tz_convert'

Comment: Did you use the entire code above? Also, can you share the version of pandas you’re using with `print(pd.__version__)`

Answer (score 0):

```
unix_timestamp=1284105682
pd.to_datetime(unix_timestamp,unit='s', utc=True).tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
```

**Output**

```
Timestamp('2010-09-10 13:31:22+0530', tz='Asia/Kolkata')
```